# How can I include child directories in a bundle pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

In the code for my bundle configuration, assume the following is declared and initialised:

```
BundleCollection bundles;
```

I have *js* files that I want to include in the following directories:

1. ~/Scripts/app
2. ~/Scripts/app/some-namespace

I've been able to include the files in the *app* directory but not its child directories by using this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include("~/Scripts/app/*.js"));
```

I would like to include all of the *js* files from *both* directories in a single bundle in the most maintainable way possible.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by doing this:

```
var appScripts = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/app", "*.js", searchSubdirectories: true);
bundles.Add(appScripts);
```